# Post an object as data using Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery

My code that I tried is as follows:

```
var dataO = new Object();
dataO.numberId = 1;
dataO.companyId = 531;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "TelephoneNumbers.aspx/DeleteNumber",
    data: "{numberId:1,companyId:531}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('In Ajax');
    }
});
```

I would like to pass the object `dataO` as the ajax data, how can I do it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I will leave my original answer in place but the below is how you need to approach it.
(Forgive me but it is a long time since I have used regular asp.net / web services with jquery:)

You need to use the following js lib [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library, you can then use the stringify method to ensure your json is in the correct format for the service.

```
var dataO = {
    numberId: "1", 
    companyId : "531"
};

var json = JSON2.stringify(dataO); 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "TelephoneNumbers.aspx/DeleteNumber",
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('In Ajax');
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Same issue / answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936767/passing-js-object-as-json-to-jquery)

Comment: @plattsy the param method was not the best when this was written. Changed in 1.4

Comment: I assume it is no longer needed to use JSON2 instead of JSON, as of 2015 (unless requiring compatibility with old browsers). Is that right?

Comment: Correct @Janos unless you targeting ie8 etc

Answer (score 9):

All arrays passed to PHP must be object literals.  Here's an example from JS/jQuery:

```
var myarray = {};  //must be declared as an object literal first

myarray[fld1] = val;  // then you can add elements and values
myarray[fld2] = val;
myarray[fld3] = Array();  // array assigned to an element must also be declared as object literal
```

etc...`

It can now be sent via Ajax in the data: parameter as follows:

```
data: { new_name: myarray },
```

PHP picks this up and reads it as a normal array without any decoding necessary.  Here's an example:

```
$array = $_POST['new_name'];  // myarray became new_name (see above)
$fld1 = array['fld1'];
$fld2 = array['fld2'];
etc...
```

However, when you return an array to jQuery via Ajax it must first be encoded using JSON.
Here's an example in PHP:

```
$return_array = json_encode($return_aray));
print_r($return_array);
```

And the output from that looks something like this:

```
{
    "fname":"James",
    "lname":"Feducia",
    "vip":"true",
    "owner":"false",
    "cell_phone":"(801) 666-0909",
    "email":"jp@gmail.com", 
    "contact_pk":"",
    "travel_agent":""
}
```

{again we see the object literal encoding tags} now this can be read by JS/jQuery as an array without any further action inside JS/jQuery...  Here's an example in jQuery ajax:

```
success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    alert( "Return Values: " + result['fname'] + " " + result['lname'] );
}
```

Comment: Also this is a very old post, but in newer Server Applications, you don't need JSON to post requests. For Example in CQmvc (https://github.com/mohamad-z/CQmvc) one can leave dataO object be dataO.numberId:1 and dataO.companyId:531 and post the data. In the Server side, your Action's argument should be DeleteNumber(ObjectRepresentingYourSpecificType dataO) and thats it

Comment: Plus one for using plain English without ambiguity when describing your example.

Answer (score 9):

Is not necessary to pass the data as JSON string, **you can pass the object directly**, without defining `contentType` or `dataType`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "TelephoneNumbers.aspx/DeleteNumber",
    data: data0,

    success: function(data)
    {
        alert('Done');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just pass the object as is. Note you can create the object as follows

```
var data0 = {numberId: "1", companyId : "531"};

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "TelephoneNumbers.aspx/DeleteNumber",
 data: dataO,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(msg) {
 alert('In Ajax');
 }
});
```

UPDATE seems an odd issue with the serializer, maybe it is expecting a string, out of interest can you try the following.

data: "{'numberId':'1', 'companyId ':'531'}",

Comment: the data is the request looks like numberId=1&companyId=531 and i get  "Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: numberId.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer

.DeserializePrimitiveObject()

Comment: can you try it with the quotes like the amended above

Comment: can you try the above? I know its not an answer but just out of interest

Comment: Yeah I did try it got the same message.

Answer (score 3):

`[object Object]`
This means somewhere the object is being converted to a string.

Converted to a string:

```
//Copy and paste in the browser console to see result

var product = {'name':'test'};
JSON.stringify(product + '');
```

Not converted to a string:

```
//Copy and paste in the browser console to see result

var product = {'name':'test'};
JSON.stringify(product);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may pass an object to the `data` option in `$.ajax`. jQuery will send this as regular post data, just like a normal HTML form.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "TelephoneNumbers.aspx/DeleteNumber",
    data: dataO, // same as using {numberId: 1, companyId: 531}
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('In Ajax');
    }
});
```

Comment: I've already tried this and my .net webmethod has issue's deserialising the request.