# how to send a map in the params of the ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have constructed a map in the java script like this now i wanna send this map in the params of the ajax request and should deconstruct it in the server side

```
 var map = new Object(); 
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var dat = arr[i];
    if (dat != null && dat.length > 0){
    var mystr = trim(dat);
    map[mystr] = Ext.getCmp(mystr).getValue();
    }
    }

Ext.Ajax.request({
url : 'Redirector?id=updateClientTeam',
params: {
//Should be able to send my map object here
},

success : function(pResponse) {
}
});
}
```

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068189/jquery-ajax-post-and-object-as-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert to json for http transport using JSON.stringify(map)