# Post object with methods using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, post, methods

I have a simple object

```
function MyClass()
{
    this.id = null;
    // ... Lot of stuff in it
}
MyClass.prototype.parse = function(text)
{
    // A parsing function that fills the object
}
```

If I try to send the object using `$.post`

```
$.post("target.php", { QUERY: "query_id", object: obj }, function(data){
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

with `obj` being an instance of `MyClass`, I get an error : `text is undefined`

How do I make it understand that I only want the data being sent, not the methods like `parse` as it wouldn't make any sens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over an object's properties by doing

```
for (var prop in obj)
```

Using that in combination with `typeof` to figure out if the property is a function, you can create a function to return all non-function properties as a new object. I whipped up this jsfiddle as an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/6w0wj8hj/

That means you can then do

```
$.post("target.php", { QUERY: "query_id", object: obj.getProperties() }, function(data){
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Nice ! What I ended up doing is putting the `getProperties` method in a `Postable` class, and make other class inherit from it :)

Answer (score 1):

When doing an Ajax call, you can only send string. It automatically converts the data to string but if it can't, like in your case, it throws an error. In this case, instead of sending obj, send obj.data (the string value).

Comment: As my obj contains a lot of fields, the automatic conversion is very nice. Is there any way to restrict it only to fields where it's possible ?

Comment: Im pretty sure this link will be really helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068189/jquery-ajax-post-and-object-as-data