# newbie ajax and php get parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need help to do something small but I don't know how to solve it.
I have a javascript file with ajax inside like this

```
$.ajax({
    data: "mc_id="+someid,
    url: "includes/getDataPrs.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(msg){
          //some function here
    }
});
```

in getDataPrs.php

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

  sec_session_start();
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $id = null;
  $date = null;
  $limit = 0;
  if (isset($_GET['mc_id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['mc_id'];
  }
  //some process here $data
  echo json_encode($data);
```

I can get data from `$_GET['mc_id']` but when I need more data and I change the parameters in javascript like this

```
$.ajax({
    data: "{'mc_id':'"+someid+"','limit':'"+somelimit+"'}",
    url: "includes/getDataPrs.php",
```

and then I got nothing in php `$_GET['mc_id']` or `$_GET['limit']`
in my desperate to solve it, I put in url `"includes/getDataPrs.php?mc_id=someid&limit=somelimit`

any comment or suggestion I truly appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: Don't quote your `data` - `"{....}"`. So `data: "{'mc_id':'"+someid+"','limit':'"+somelimit+"'}"` should be `data: {'mc_id': someid, 'limit': somelimit }`

Comment: either you can send the parameter like data: "mc_id="+someid+"&limit="+somelimit ,or  read it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068189/jquery-ajax-post-and-object-as-data

Answer (score 5):

passing multiple variable in `ajax` should be like

```
$.ajax({
    data: {mc_id: someid, limit: some_limit},
    url: "includes/getDataPrs.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(msg){
      //some function here
    }
});
```

It is always better to use `data: {mc_id: someid, limit: some_limit}` because it will treated like object itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try using following syntax for sending data in ajax function:

```
...
data:{mc_id:someid,limit:somelimit},
...
```

Without using quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Change from

```
data: "{'mc_id':'"+someid+"','limit':'"+somelimit+"'}",
```

To

```
data: "mc_id="+someid+"&limit="+somelimit,
```

Comment: check my answer.Suggested for change not to use
data: "{'mc_id':'"+someid+"','limit':'"+somelimit+"'}",

Comment: I can get data from $_GET['mc_id'] but when I need more data and I change the parameters in javascript like this

$.ajax({
data: "{'mc_id':'"+someid+"','limit':'"+somelimit+"'}",
url: "includes/getDataPrs.php",

and then I got nothing in php $_GET['mc_id'] or $_GET['limit'] in my desperate to solve it, I put in url "includes/getDataPrs.php?mc_id=someid&limit=somelimit

Comment: check last line of question .What he wants

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

```
1) Replace `data: "mc_id="+someid,` with `data: { mc_id: someid},`. (required)
2) Now you can get your data in PHP file like `$_POST['mc_id']` (optional). It is better to use `type: 'POST'`in your jQuery code.
```

So below is your whole code:

```
$.ajax({
data: { mc_id: someid},
url: "includes/getDataPrs.php",
type: 'POST',
dataType: "json",
async: false,
success: function(msg){
      //some function here
}});
```

**in getDataPrs.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

  sec_session_start();
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $id = null;
  $date = null;
  $limit = 0;
  if (isset($_POST['mc_id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['mc_id'];
  }
  //some process here $data
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/getDataPrs.php",
    data: {'mc_id': someid, 'limit': somelimit}.done(function (response) {
        //
    });
});
```