# Want to search by product_id and fetch all the data based on product_id in form field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, product, inventory

I'm building an Inventory management system but stuck with a search query.

I've tables named:

1. products
2. product_purchases
3. product_sales

Now, want to get product details from "products" table by searching "product_id" and fetch/show the product details in the appropriate HTML fields then add/insert the product details data into "product_purchases" table.

Similarly, want to get product details from "product_purchases" table by searching "product_purchase_id" and fetch/show the product details in the appropriate HTML fields then add/insert the product details data into "product_sales" table.

The problem is - I used $.post method to query my product details but it won't work.

Here I just added the screenshot of my purchase

[image: Purchase Page]

code of my purchase page:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-search">             
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_id" id="product_id" placeholder="Search a product by ID">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button name="searchProduct" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>


<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset id="general-settings">
    <legend><h3 class="fields-heading">Item details</h3></legend>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['addPurchase'])){
            $product_id = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['product_id']));
            $product_name = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['product_name']));
            $supplier_name = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['supplier_name']));
            $brand_name = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['brand_name']));
            $group_name = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['group_name']));
            $unit_price = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['unit_price']));
            $quantity = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['quantity']));
            $bonus_quantity = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['bonus_quantity']));
            $total_price = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['total_price']));
            $total_bonus_price = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['total_bonus_price']));
            $unit_sale_price = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['unit_sale_price']));

            if ( empty($product_id) && empty($product_name) && empty($supplier_name) && empty($brand_name) && empty($group_name) && empty($unit_price) && empty($quantity) && empty($bonus_quantity) && empty($total_price) && empty($total_bonus_price) && empty($unit_sale_price) ){
                echo "<p class='text-error'>Star (*) marks are required fields and cannot be empty!</p>";
            }else{
                $insert = $db->insert("purchases", "product_id, product_name, supplier_id, brand_id, group_id, unit_price, quantity, bonus_quantity, total_price, total_bonus_price, unit_sale_price", "'$product_id', '$product_name', '$supplier_name', '$brand_name', '$group_name', '$unit_price', '$quantity', '$bonus_quantity', '$total_price', $total_bonus_price, '$unit_sale_price'");

                if($insert){ ?>
                    <script>
                        alert("Product added successfully!");
                        window.location.assign("inventory-purchase.php");
                    </script>
                <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<p class='text-error'>Product not added!</p>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    <table class="table table-responsive table-settings">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="product_id">Product ID <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_id" id="product_id"></td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="product_name">Name <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" id="product_name"></td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="supplier_name">Supplier <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="supplier_name" id="supplier_name">
                        <option>Select a supplier</option>
                        <?php $getsuppliers = $db->select("supplier_id, supplier_name", "suppliers"); 
                            if ($getsuppliers) {
                                while ( $getsplr = $getsuppliers->fetch_assoc() ){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $getsplr['supplier_id']; ?>"><?php echo $getsplr['supplier_name']; ?></option>
                        <?php  } }?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="brand_name">Brand <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="brand_name" id="brand_name">
                        <option>Select a brand</option>                                                                                  <?php $getbrands = $db->select("brand_id, brand_name", "brands"); 
                            if ($getbrands) {
                                while ( $getbrnd = $getbrands->fetch_assoc() ){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $getbrnd['brand_id']; ?>"><?php echo $getbrnd['brand_name']; ?></option>
                        <?php  } }?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="group_name">Group <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="group_name" id="group_name">
                        <option>Select a group</option>
                        <?php $getgroups = $db->select("group_id, group_name", "groups"); 
                            if ($getgroups) {
                                while ( $getgrp = $getgroups->fetch_assoc() ){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $getgrp['group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $getgrp['group_name']; ?></option>
                        <?php  } }?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="unit_price">Unit price <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit_price" id="unit_price">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="quantity">Quantity <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity"></td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="bonus_quantity">Bonus Quantity</label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="bonus_quantity" id="bonus_quantity"></td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="total_price">Total price</label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total_price" id="total_price">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="total_bonus_price">Total bonus price</label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total_bonus_price" id="total_bonus_price">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <td><label for="unit_sale_price">Unit sale price <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit_sale_price" id="unit_sale_price">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="addPurchase" value="Add purchase" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-register"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and sale product page.

[image: sale Page]

ocde of my sales page

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-search">             
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_id" id="product_id" placeholder="Search a product by ID">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button name="searchProduct" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>

<?php 
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $product_id = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['product_id']));
        $product_name = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['product_name']));
        $unit_sale_price = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['unit_sale_price']));
        $quantity = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['quantity']));
        $total_sale_price = $frmt->sanitize(mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['total_sale_price']));

        if ( empty($product_id) && empty($quantity) ){
            echo "<p class='text-error'>Star (*) marks are required fields and cannot be empty!</p>";
        }else{
            $insert = $db->insert("sales", "product_id, product_name, unit_sale_price, quantity, total_sale_price", "'$product_id', '$product_name', '$unit_price', '$quantity', '$total_sale_price'");

            if($insert){ ?>
                <script>
                    alert("Product sent to invoice successfully!");
                    window.location.assign("inventory-sale.php");
                </script>
            <?php
            }else{
                echo "<p class='text-error'>Product not sent to invoice!</p>";
            }
        }
    }
?> 
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset id="general-settings">
        <legend><h3 class="fields-heading">Item details</h3></legend>
        <table class="table table-responsive table-settings">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <td><label for="product_id">Product ID <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_id" id="product_id" placeholder="Search an item by ID"></td>
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <td><label for="product_name">Product name</label></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="product_name" id="product_name" value=""></td>
                </div>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <td><label for="unit_sale_price">Unit sale price</label></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <input type="number" readonly class="form-control" name="unit_sale_price" id="unit_sale_price" value="">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <td><label for="quantity">Quantity <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity"></td>
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <td><label for="total_sale_price">Total price</label></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <input readonly type="text" disabled class="form-control" name="total_sale_price" id="total_sale_price">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="sale_invoice" value="Sent to invoice" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-register"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

FYI: I'm working with PHP OOP, but not any framework.

Anybody around to help me out of this problem?

Comment: Post your code so we can help

Comment: Added the code, plz have a look.

Comment: All this sanitisation is essentially futile. Please see about prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ajax request with post method to get data and populate in your forms and archive your next step

[how to use ajax with OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068189/post-an-object-as-data-using-jquery-ajax)

It help you get data without refreshing and populate in your form fields. Same for PHP just call your controller with ajax request then same OOP way get data from database from Model and return data in JSON format and use in your fields.

Need more information feel free to ask :)