# Node.js + body-parser object format changes when it reaches backend

Tags: json, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to send an object inside an another object from React frontend to Node/express backend using jquery ajax. The problem the data is received at the backend, it no longer looks follows the syntax of an object. Instead, it looks something like this:

```
{ 'data[name]': 'test name',
  'data[size][height]': '123',
  'data[size][weight]': '50' }
```

Here is the front end ajax call...

```
lendItem(){
    let id = "5af3348742afc60ab71d7d80"

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/items/' + id,
        method: 'put',
        data: {
            'data': {
                name: "test name",
                size: {
                    height: 123,
                    weight: 50
                }
            }
        },
        success: (res) => {console.log(res)}
    });

}
```

backend server...

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/promedical');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// parsing data that was received
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// initialize routes
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

// error handling
app.use((err, req, res, next)=>{
    res.status(422).send({error: err.message});
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

...and here is the route I'm interested in.

```
router.put('/items/:id', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("success");
});
```

I think this problem might have something to do with that body-parser. Is is possible to send objects inside an object via jquery ajax and have it keep it's form once it reaches the backend? If not, should I just send all the data inside one object and then parse it at the backend?

Comment: I do not understand your problem right, you want to create an object with another object inside is this? And the syntax you're using does not satisfy what you want? The content of this link does not help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068189/post-an-object-as-data-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Did you try adding `dataType: 'json',` and `contentType: "application/json"` to your ajax object?

Comment: What I want is to take that data at frontend, send it to backend and then store it in a Mongodb database in json format. However, when the data arrives at the backend, it no longer follows the regular json syntax. Instead, it has these square brackets for some reason. If I try to store the data in a database in that form, it won't work. Nothing gets saved into the database. I was wondering if there is a way to retain the original json format when sending objects inside another object via ajas.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the object called 'data' becomes a string after the backend has accepted the ajax call. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I need to store that object into a database as an object, not as a string.