# How to post JQUERY data as object?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have a bunch of `input` in my form with the same name attribute.

`<input name="userName[]">`

On form submit, in my Nodejs post route, I was collecting the object as

`var userName=req.body.userName`

I was then looping through this by doing something like

```
for(let i=0;i<userName.length;i++){
     //insert Username into the database
}
```

However, for some reason, I cannot use the form submit anymore. Now I am doing `e.preventDefault` and using jQuery to send my POST data.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/orderDetails",
        data:{
            userName:$('input[name="userName[]"]').val(),
        }
    });
```

However, now if I do `console.log(typeof(userName))` in my Nodejs Backend, it returns `string`. This means I can no longer perform loops anymore. Is there a way to make jQuery send the object instead of a string?

Comment: Have you tried `serializeArray` yet? What was the output for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post an object as data using Jquery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068189/post-an-object-as-data-using-jquery-ajax)