# How to convert JSon Object to Java Object?

Tags: java, json, spring

Can Anyone help me on this, i m trying to convert complex json object send through ajax into a object. so that i can use this object to pass into my model.

The JSP code is:

```
function callRemovefilter()
{
    var jsonObjects = {
        address1: "Address_1",
        city: "City",
        pin: "PIN"
        };
    var jsonObjects2 = {
        locality:"Loc1",
        shippingType:"Regular",
        shippingCost:20
    };

    var cust= JSON.stringify(jsonObjects);
    var sales=JSON.stringify(jsonObjects2);
    jQuery.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost:8080/OnlineStore/kmsg/grocery/SaveSalesOrder",
              type: "GET",
              data: {CustomerInfo:cust,SalesModel:sales},
              dataType: "json",
              beforeSend: function(x) {
                if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                  x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
                }
              },
              success: function(result) {
             //Write your code here
              }
    });
}
```

// The controller code is

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/SaveSalesOrder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
            public @ResponseBody String SaveCustomerOrder(@RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams) throws Exception 
            {       
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                SalesCommandObject salesCommandObject= new SalesCommandObject();
                salesCommandObject = objectMapper.readValue(body, SalesCommandObject .class);


                return "Success";
            }
```

// Code of JSP to send object to controller

```
var salesCommandObject = {};                      salesCommandObject.CustomerInfo =
            {
            "address1": "Address_1",
            "city": "City",
            "pin": "PIN"
            };
salesCommandObject.SalesModel = 
            {
            "locality":'Loc1',
            "shippingType":'Regular',
            "shippingCost":20
            };

           $.ajax
           ({
              type: "POST",
              dataType : 'json',
              async : true,     
              url: "http://localhost:8080/OnlineStore/kmsg/grocery/SaveSalesOrder",
              data : JSON.stringify(salesCommandObject),
              }).done(function(data,type,xml)
                        {
                                                  console.log(data);
                        }).fail(function()
                                  {
                            alert("Something Bad Happened, Service failed");
                      })
```

Comment: Answer for the similar question click on Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430898/mapping-json-object-send-by-ajax-post-to-spring-mvc-model

Answer (score 0):

Send objects, not jsonstrigs. And in controller in your method SaveCustomerOrder get an object, not Map, like:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/SaveSalesOrder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
            public @ResponseBody String SaveCustomerOrder(@RequestParam  CustomerInfo ci, @RequestParam SalesModel sm) throws Exception 
            {

               //your logic here
                return "Success";
            }`
And add getters and setters to appropriate classes(i.e CustomerInfo, SalesModel) like:

```
`public class SalesModel{
    private String sale_id;//or whatever field or property you need
    public String getSale_Id() {
        return sale_id;
    }
    public void setSale_Id(String si) {
        this.sale_id = si;
    }

}`
```

Comment: u r saying to send Json Object not string ? is there any problem, in the way i am sending the json data. am i not sending the json object , if not then how ?   also when i try using my model objects as parameters to my controller method then error thrown by firebug is unsupported media type,

Comment: send javascript objects! if you set your getters and setters properly, it should work

Comment: please, more about exception

Comment: i m new to jquery, can u show me the sample for sending objects properly ?

Comment: var saveData = {};
    saveData.one = "test";
    saveData.two = "tes2";


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyService.aspx/GetDate",
        data: JSON.stringify(saveData),      // NOTE CHANGE HERE
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function(msg) {
        alert('error');
        }

    });

Comment: very similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936767/passing-js-object-as-json-to-jquery

Comment: 400 Bad Request Message Called  from server

Comment: HTTP Status 400 - <u>Required SalesCommandObject
 parameter 'salesCommandObject' is not present</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the
 client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.15</h3></body></html

Comment: that means that you send parameter called "salesCommandObject", but in controller you don't get it in parameters. your parameter name must be equal to the name of parameter that you send via ajax.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/SaveSalesOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST )
 
 public @ResponseBody String SaveCustomerOrder(@RequestParam SalesCommandObject salesCommandObject) throws Exception 
 {  
   CustomerModel cust = salesCommandObject.getCustomerInfo();

  System.out.println(cust.getAddress1());
  return "Success";
 }

Comment: i am passing the parameter but still server shows this message ?  400 : Bad Request with same exception !

Comment: i have updated the question code and added the view code for sending json object...

Comment: add " contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8","  in your ajax

Comment: i have added it in the ajax, but the problem remains same ? can u help me.. How to get rid of this.

Comment: Oh, sorry, use "@RequestBody" instead of "@RequestParam"

Comment: like  "@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/searchTopic")
    public AjaxResponse searchTopic(@RequestParam String id, @RequestBody QueryTransitionObject query) throws Exception {
        List<Analytics> analytics = analyticsService.searchTopic(id, query);
        return new AjaxResponse(analytics);
    }"

Comment: did you add settend and getters to your SalesCommandObject  class? for all your properties!