# How to pass javascript variable through url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

I need to pass `JavaScript(jQuery)` variable through url, so I can catch it in `$_GET` with php. Here is what i have tried already:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var click=0;
    $('#next').click(function(){
        var count=$('#next').val();//ovdje imamo koliko je maksimalna proslidjena vrijednost
        var data = {};
        click++;
        if(click>=count){
            click=count;
        }
        data.clicks=click;

        window.location.replace('https://www.servis-racunara.net/pages/notifications_page.php?click='+click);
    });
});
```

Doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var click = 0;
    $('#next').click(function () {
        var count = $('#next').val();//ovdje imamo koliko je maksimalna proslidjena vrijednost
        var data = {};
        click++;
        if (click >= count) {
            click = count;
        }
        data.clicks = click;
        $.get("notifications_page.php",
            { page: clicks },
            function () {

            });
    });
});
```

Doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var click=0;
    $('#next').click(function(){
        var count=$('#next').val();//ovdje imamo koliko je maksimalna proslidjena vrijednost
        var data = {};
        click++;
        if(click>=count){
            click=count;
        }
        data.clicks=click;
        $.ajax({
            url: "notifications_page.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: data,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

This works, but strangely. It sends parameter, but I cannot catch it with `$_GET` in `PHP`. Please help if you have some idea how to handle this.
**UPDATE:**
When I look at `Inspect` tool under `Network` here is what I see:
[image]

Everything works fine but I don't know how to catch this parameter because in my page here is how `$_GET` looks like: 
[image]

I think that page should be reloaded in order for `$_GET` to catch parameter. What do you think?

**SECOND UPDATE:** 
I found a way to put this variable `click` in url with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var click=0;
        $('#next').click(function(){
            var count=$('#next').val();//ovdje imamo koliko je maksimalna proslidjena vrijednost

            click++;
            if(click>=count){
                click=count;
            }

            $('a').attr('href','?id='+click);
});
        });
```

This last line does it all. But now my counter doesn't work, due to reloading of page(href attribute). Can you please help me now just to fix that?

Comment: Remove dataType: JSON ;)

Comment: can you please share the relevant part of `notifications_page.php`?

Comment: check your script properly go to "notifications_page.php" or not. If its work means first test echo msg. after use $_GET['clicks']

Comment: @briosheje relevant part meaning what?

Comment: @Ognj3n : the part where you actually acquire the data ;) (the one with the $_GET)

Comment: `if(isset($_GET)){
 var_dump($_GET['clicks']);
}`

Comment: @Ognj3n do you want to send data via ajax ? In your first example you are not using ajax and in rest of two you are using that.

Comment: I just want that parameter to be passed through url. I tried those few attempts, but in the end it doesn't metter how i will do that. It just needs to work.

Comment: I would personally suggest you to use a post request for such instead, please check this "live" example: https://jsfiddle.net/g9yv7zop/ (please note that instead of data: { json:  you simply need data: <your stringified object here>. (and in your PHP script, get the data using `$_POST['clicks']`, and answer: `echo json_encode($_POST['clicks'])` )

Comment: @briosheje Can you see my last update and try to help me, because I'm almost done with this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a JS object as data. Perform a JSON.stringify on your data before passing it to the AJAX call and it will work. Example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "notifications_page.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {

        }
});
```

Reference: [Passing js object as json to jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936767/passing-js-object-as-json-to-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

try this structure in your ajax part,

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        "count": count
      },
      url: "notifications_page.php",
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Success");
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert("fail");
      }
```